# converting java String into 7 bit String

Tags: java, android, string, sms

I'm encrypting a string say "hello h r u"
Using encryption algorithm and getting the encrypted String as `b�*-ت5Tr���6=`

This String we cannot send as an sms
So i want to convert to sms supported format by converting it into 7 bit.
and on the receiver side we have to convert back into 8 bit and decrypt.
How can i achieve this?

Note: I have used Base64 to convert into sms supported format but the length is increasing.
So iam not able to send more character

Comment: You ask 'how can I achieve this' - yet you then say you've successfully base 64 encoded it. So you've solved your problem, yes? Is your only problem the size increase due to the base 64 encoding?

Comment: yes i want size to not increase much

Comment: [Base 64 encoding has roughly a 33% overhead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) - you've trying to encode the same data, but with less information density.  You won't escape this.  What's your actual question?

Comment: i want the size to not increase much and also the string has to be in sms supported format can we change the 8bit to 7 bit and send. is it possible if it is possible how can it be done

Comment: You are asking for base128. There are implementations available on google

Comment: You've got the solution - you need to encode the data using something like Base64.  Read about Base64 encoding and you'll learn why you can't escape the character count increasing.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008047/why-dont-people-use-base128-in-javascript -- SMS uses a 7-bit character set.

Comment: Greg -> since sms is 7 bit it will match base128. In the event that sms 7 bit and base128 does not use the same chars, it is a simple matter of changing the letters used in an base128 implementation and making his own version of base128

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen: actually - you're right - all the SMS alphabet is printable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your question is something like:

> How can I transmit my binary data as valid SMS text without increasing the size of the message?

The answer for this is - you can't - at least not with 100% certainty.

Your encryption algorithm probably creates some byte array (`byte[]`) which will grow by around 33% (as stated in the above comments) once you **Base64** encode it.

The only option I see is to attempt to compress the information either before or after encryption - depending on which compression algorithm you choose - and then **Base64** encode it.  This will give you a better chance of making the size limit - but nothing definitive. (Unless you find a compression algorithm which promises to compress by more than 33% for every input.

An alternative is to span the message over two SMS messages - assuming you are allowed to do that.